# Hibernate Bidirectional Mapping Results in Cycle when using converter for DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-6

I've mapped the classes as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ITEMS_ID")
private CategoryItem categoryItem;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="categoryItem",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<CategoryRating> categoryRatingList;
```

But when I need to convert the table models to dto's I'm caught in a cycle as:

```
 target.setCategoryRatingDtoList(categoryRatingConverter.convert(source.getCategoryRatingList()));

 target.setCategoryItemDto(categoryItemConverter.convertToDto(source.getCategoryItem()));
```

both converters end up calling each other.

I need the result as:

List of CategoryItems, in which every CategoryItems object contains a list of associated CategoryRatings

How should I solve this problem? Maybe I'm using bidirectional mapping in the wrong sense. Anyhow, kindly provide your opinion and possible solutions for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options.

You could introduce a context and register objects to that context in their constructors. When another object is then in it's constructor it can receive an inflight list/object through that context and thus resolve the cycle this way.

Another option is to make the DTOs mutable and first instantiate the objects as well as register them into a context, before setting the state on the objects. This is similar to the first solution with the slight difference that the DTO class doesn't need to know about the context.

The third solution is that you avoid the cycle by using a simpler converter for e.g. `CategoryRating` within the `CategoryItemConverter` that only converts some data, but not the `categoryRatings` list.